# how to resolve Javascript issues when using 2sxc IRenderService to embed an App in a DNN Theme Layout

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

Im trying to embed my 2sxc App into a Theme layout page.
The App view html does render

```
<%-- This namespace provides this.GetScopedService<T>() --%>
<%@ Import Namespace="ToSic.Sxc.Dnn" %>
<%-- This namespace provides all the common 2sxc services --%>
<%@ Import Namespace="ToSic.Sxc.Services" %>

<%= this.GetScopedService<IRenderService>().Module(1041,3421) %>
```

, but its Javascript crashes.

The App uses its own API for searching.

```
1. // get the sxc-controller for this module
2. var sxc = $2sxc(3421);
3. // now get the data in the promise
4. sxc.webApi.get('app/auto/api/Forms/SearchForm')
5.   .then(data => {
6.     console.log(data)
7.   });
```

originally line 2 crashed saying $2sxc is not recognised.
we resolved that by adding this script reference to our layout page

```
<script src="/desktopmodules/tosic_sexycontent/js/2sxc.api.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And now it crashes on line 4 when trying to use sxc.webApi.get

```
Uncaught Can't find page - something went wrong, pls contact 2sxc.org
```

It seems I need to include another JS script.
I tried to also include

```
<script src="/desktopmodules/tosic_sexycontent/dist/inpage/inpage.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

but that made it worse

Comment: resolved by adding this

 var page = GetService<ToSic.Sxc.Services.IPageService>();
page.Activate("2sxc.JsCore");

Now need to resolve the pageID, moduleID mismatch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this by adding this

var page = GetService<ToSic.Sxc.Services.IPageService>();

page.Activate("2sxc.JsCore");

Comment: Two things, 1) don't forget to mark this as answered. 2) if you have upgraded to v14+ already, you can skip the `var page...` and just do `Kit.Page.Activate();` now. Lots of good examples of this any of the recently updated 2sxc Apps on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

Update: to use the JS better in the theme, I've just pushed an update to 14.07.04.

Basically you can force a different context than the automatic one, using

```
var sxc = $2sxc({ pageId: 27, moduleId: 42, zoneId: 3, appId: 8});
sxc.webApi.fetchJson(...).then(...);
```

this uses the context identifier https://docs.2sxc.org/api/js/ContextIdentifier.html#Api_Js_SxcJs_ContextIdentifier which has existed for a few versions now, but there was a bug that was fixed in 14.07.04

See also https://docs.2sxc.org/api/js/SxcGlobal.html#Api_Js_SxcJs_SxcGlobal_get_3

Comment: Awesome, I did try the context identifier in 14.03 , but it didn't seem to help. Will test this today. Thanks again Daniel

Comment: Wow, this is awesome, glad I read this, thanks!!